# Query from java to php is cut by something

Tags: java, php

I have rather strange situation. I've created some questions about my problem before, but I found out that root of problem was completely different. 
Java coder sends me a post query:
This how I log his query:

```
$query = file_get_contents("php://input");
$queryFile= fopen("/pathtofile/querylog.txt","wb");
fwrite($queryFile, $query);
fclose($queryFile);
```

Then I receive image from his query(image may have Content-Length header or not)

```
$query = preg_replace('/[\s\r\n]+/', '', $query);
$queryHex=pack("H*", $query);
if (preg_match("/Content-Length:[\s]+([0-9]+)([^|]*)\-\-\-\-[0-9]+boundary\-\-/", $queryHex))
{
    preg_match_all("/Content-Length:[\s]+([0-9]+)([^|]*)\-\-\-\-[0-9]+boundary\-\-/", $queryHex, $matches);
    $inputImage=$matches[2][0];
    $inputImage=trim($inputImage);
}
else
{
    $inputImage=$queryHex;
    $inputImage=trim($inputImage);
}
```

Next I create image:

```
$imageFile=fopen("pathtophile/inputPhoto.jpg", 'wb');
fwrite($imageFile, $inputImage);
fclose($imageFile);
```

So, the problem:
Java coder tests my script. And it generates file of photo that can't be opened and has size 17 k byte (original size is 35 k).
I take a content of querylog.txt put it in my Advanced Rest Client, send query to the same script and it generates fine photo with size 35 k byte.
WTF? Where can his query be changed? I do nothing with it after code I've posted.
**UPDATE** If you need additional information, please ask me, if I can, I'll tell it to you.

Comment: I'm no expert on any of the relevant matters of this post, but my guess is that your pattern matching is trimming something of the data?

Comment: All queries, He sent me last two days have not Content-Length. May be trim can cause it only at java?)